# Not operator for using keyup operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with few open text boxes. One of the boxes will have auto filled as 100 and I have made that readonly. I want if respondent enters 100 in any other box I give an alert and clear the value. This is working for me. However I want to use this alert function only for text boxes which is NOT auto filled and readonly. Not sure if I am using :not operator correct or not. Rest script is working.

Below is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('input').val()=='100')
      $(this).children('input').prop('readOnly',true);
  });
  $('input:text:not(readonly)').on('keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='100')
    {
      alert("Please provide answer between 0-99.");
      $(this).val("");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:not([readonly])')
```

should work for both readonly=true and readonly=readonly

Answer (score 2):

Use **[attribute equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** in `:not`:

```
$('input:text:not([readonly])').on('keyup',function(){
 if($(this).val()=='100')
 {
   alert("Please provide answer between 0-99.");
   $(this).val("");
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is not working for me..when I am going to readonly text using tab key..it is still giving me alert and removing piped value.

Comment: @Vaibhav: can you share the demo.also try using `:not([readonly])`